# Is there a potential market for paid answers to physics questions? If not, why?

Tags: discussion

Hope this isn't closed without explanation...

There are sites like JustAnswer.com where customers can pay for in-depth answers to their questions by validated experts.  The experts are typically lawyers, doctors, repairmen and the like.  Some customers like the speed, privacy and convenience of this.  My question is ... could this work with physicists and scientists in general?  If you are a physicist, would you be willing to do your best to answer a question, say by an entrepreneur or another scientist, for a fee of around $70?  Do you think there are customers out there for the service?

Comment: Whether or not there is a market, Physics Stackexchange isn't the place for it, so this doesn't really seem to be appropriate for Physics Stackexchange Meta.

Comment: Agreed; SE is gratis [by design](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq), what makes this Q off-topic.

Comment: Sure, professional physicists sometimes do consulting work, but it hopefully pays a lot better.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think so, for the reasons here:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/06/the-vast-and-endless-sea.html

> It turns out that traditional carrot-and-stick incentives are only useful for repetitive, mechanical tasks. The minute you have to do anything even slightly complex that requires even a little problem solving without a clear solution or rules -- those incentives not only don't work, they make things worse!

Lots of research supporting this.